# Incorrrect URL to repository for 3d party plugins in Gradle for Android App

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

During the work on update to new target Android SDK, the Grardle shows the error:

`Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin', version: '0.14.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources`

It happens with all of 3d party plugins. The detailed log shows incorrect urls to the repositories:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jitpack.io/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://www.myget.org/F/abtsoftware/maven/com/facebook/testing/screenshot/plugin/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin/0.14.0/com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin.gradle.plugin-0.14.0.pom]
```

Here are my declarations of plugins in

**Project Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.20' apply false
    id "com.facebook.testing.screenshot.plugin" version "0.14.0" apply false
    id 'io.realm.kotlin' version '1.13.0' apply false
}
```

**Module Gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' 
    id 'io.realm.kotlin'
}
```

The project contains several modules.

Clean Project and Invalidate caches did not worked.

No idea why the URLs are incorrect and how can I fix them.

Thanks in advance for the help.